# Rails config.exceptions_app not working if I directly hit the 'localhost:3000/404' endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I am trying to configure the exceptions app in a Rails API to return custom JSONs for 404/422/500 instead of the default error screen. So far I have done like this:

```rb
# application.rb
config.exceptions_app = routes
```

```rb
# routes.rb
get '/404', to: 'application#not_found'
get '/422', to: 'application#unacceptable'
get '/500', to: 'application#internal_error'
```

```rb
# application_controller.rb
def not_found
  render json: { error: 'Not found' }, status: :not_found
end
# Likewise, implemented methods for 422 and 500
```

```rb
# development.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

When I test this in the dev server by sending a GET request to a non-existing endpoint, like `http://localhost:3000/nonexistingroute`, it correctly returns the JSON created in `application#not_found`.
In the console log, I see the error being handled with `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/nonexistingroute")`.

However, if I try to test the routes directly like `GET http://localhost:3000/404`, it returns a 200 status with the original Rails error screen saying `"The page you were looking for doesn't exist. ... If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."`

Since I see nothing in the console log, I imagine that it's not hitting my route at all. Am I missing something? Is some additional setup necessary to get the exceptions app to work?

I have referred to these questions but none of them answered mine:
[config.exceptions_app not working in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45805920/11249670)
[Disable all html exception rendering in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16108286/11249670)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I hadn't deleted the Rails default html files such as `public/404.html`. The app would route to these files if you directly hit the endpoints like `localhost:3000/404`. Now that I've deleted these files, all three endpoints return a `404` status with the desired json.